# Cache Results Automatically

Tags: sql-server, azure

Is it possible to cache the results of a query or Stored Procedure in the below mentioned way.

Lets say Row 3, 5 and 7 are returned for a particular query with variables 1, 2 and 3. So, as long as Rows 3, 5 and 7 and not updated/deleted, for the same query set the results should be sent from the cache. And once the above rows are updated/deleted, automatically the cache for the variable set has to be updated.

Is there a way to do it. 
I am using the following 
Microsoft SQL Server Database (SQL Azure) 
Microsoft MVC 5 as API server 

I am aware of Azure SQL Data WareHousing option, though I haven't used it myself. Is there a more simple cost effective thing to do.

Comment: Non-durable in memory-optimized tables

Comment: Easy, cheap, effective. Pick two.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Cheap, Effective

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side caching in ASP.NET Web API.  If the parameters don't change, the end user will get cached results without going to the database

[ASP.NET Core
Implementing Caching In Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-caching-in-web-api/)

Comment: But what if the values on the db changes, the Web API client will not be aware of it. So, instead is there something that can be done at the SQL's end to overcome this issue.

Comment: I would say,  figure out the max length of time you want to cache , then go to db.  Otherwise what you're essentially describing is the need not to cache if you want up to the moment accuracy